# the javascript only works when some css rules are inline

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to make an interactive web page with the css part and javascript separated from the html document.

**sandbox.html** (part of it):

```
    <body>
        <nav class="unify-bg">
                <ul>
                        <li><a id="ipsum" style="top:-90px">Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
        </nav>
    </body>
```

**sandbox.css** (part of it):

```
nav li a{
    float:left;
    margin: 0 5px;
    color: #e4b05c;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 120px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color:#e4b05c;
    position: relative;
    top:-90px;
}
```

**sandbox.js** (part of it):

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("ipsum").addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
        ipsum = this;
        var t = setInterval(function () {
            move(ipsum, t);
        }, 10);
    }, false);
}

function move(element, interval) {
    var pos = element.style.top.replace("px", "");
    if (pos > -10) clearInterval(interval);
    else {
        pos = parseInt(pos) + 10;
        element.style.top = pos + "px";
    }
}
```

somehow if I remove the inline style "top:-90px" from the list element (since the style is already in the *.css anyway), the javascript stops working. Can anyone explain why please and help me solve the problem? Thank you!

Comment: It "stops working" because `element.style.top` will return an empty string (the element doesn't have a style set after all). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle to get the computed style.

Comment: @FelixKling Yes but why will it return an empty string. Are you saying window.onload runs as soon as the window is loading?? If this is the case why won't it work if I put the javascript under the nav element??  without the window.onload (that is starting from document.getElement... and not forget to remove the closing curly bracket from the window.onload's anonymous function)

Comment: *"but why will it return an empty string"* Because `element.style` returns the inline style of elements. If you don't set any inline style, it can only return an empty string. *"Are you saying window.onload runs as soon as the window is loading"* I didn't say anything about `window.onload`, but the function is called *after* the document is completely loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`element.style` only returns inline styles. Hence, without an inline `top`, it is an empty string,

If you want all applied styles, use [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle): `window.getComputedStyle(element).top`.